# Callback API for getting response from fygaro payment gateway

Tags: hooks, rest-api, callbacks

I am using fygaro payment gateway.
On successful payment , I am getting json response from fygaro on fygaro's domain itself.
But on successful payment, I want to store some data in database for that what i need to do can someone help?
Currently I am using call back api,
code is as follows,

```
<?php

function svapp_fygaro_payment_check( WP_REST_Request $request ) {
    global $wpdb;

    header( 'HTTP/1.1 200 OK' );// Takes raw data from the request
    $json = file_get_contents(' php://input');// Converts it into a PHP object
    $data = json_decode($json);//Verify Data and assign to php variable
    $order_id = isset($data->customReference) ? $data->customReference : null;
    $createdAt = isset($data->createdAt) ? $data->createdAt : null;
    $jwt = isset($data->jwt) ? $data->jwt : null;

    //Add your code here.
    if(isset($jwt)){
        $amountpaid =  isset($jwt->amount) ? $jwt->amount : null;
        $clientData=  isset($jwt->clientData) ? $jwt->clientData : null;
    }
    //It should update table after successfull payment
    if(isset($data) || isset($jwt)){

        $res=$wpdb->insert('sv_payment_fygaro', array(
            'post_id' => '118',
            'external_reference' =>  $order_id,
            'paymentstatus' => '1',
            'jwt' => $jwt,
            'amount'=>$amountpaid,
            'createdAt'=>$createdAt,
        ));

    }

    return new WP_REST_Response( $res, 200 );
}
```

Comment: can you fix the code block? It has no indenting and lots of random `<br>` tags. Also it's not clear what the problem is, you described that you want to store data on a callback, but not what the question is, e.g. is the problem that your callback is never called? That it has a fatal php error? That your table is never updated? Please be specific, use the `Edit` link to update and modify your question to add more information. That includes information about how you're registering the endpoint, as well as what the `sv_payment_fygaro` is and where it comes from. Are you using WooCommerce?

Comment: `$jwt` appears to be an object of some kind, since you're looking for `$jwt->amount` and `$jwt->clientData`. But in your `insert` statement you're treating it like it's a scalar value on the line `'jwt' => $jwt`. You may need to [`serialize`](https://php.net/serialize) or [`json_encode()`](https://php.net/json_encode) that value if you want to add it to the DB.

Comment: Actually none of the values are inserting in my database. Atleast static  values should be inserted so I will check about JWT data format. post_id and paymentstatus are also not inserting.